# What does the phrase "DV-Undefined" and the phrase "DV-MPS General" mean in book titles

Tags: book-title

I'm looking at a couple of books on Amazon and the they have some weird parts in the title.

see:

- [http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0735611319/ref=cm_rdp_product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735611319)
- [http://www.amazon.co.uk/Code-Hidden-Language-DV-MPS-General/dp/073560505X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/073560505X)

Does anyone have a clue what the phrase "DV-Undefined" and the phrase "DV-MPS General" mean in book titles?

Which is better?

Comment: Hm. Appears to be some sort of classification. There's also "DV-MPS Programming", "DV-MPS Designing", "DV-MPS Inside"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what "DV" stands for, but looking through the books listed when searching Amazon for [dv-mps](http://www.amazon.com/s?search-alias=books&keywords=dv-mps) showed that "MPS" almost definitely stands for "Microsoft Press Series."

(My first guess for "DV" was "digital version" until I saw the results were all printed books.)

The last word in the group appears to stand for what series the books are in. For instance, common series groups are Programming, Designing, and Inside—each of which relates to a particular Microsoft Press series of books.

So in this case, "Undefined" means the series isn't defined, and "General" means that it's just a general (i.e., non-series) book.

The only real differences between the two books you linked:

- The hardcover

  - published in 1999
  - doesn't have an edition number
  - costs more
- The paperback

  - published in 2000
  - is listed as the second edition
  - costs less

Which book is "better" is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I wasn't sure if one came with a DVD Disc and the other didn't, or one was digital version etc. But, Yes - I think its just a classification thing - MPS = "Microsoft Programming Series"